# SpringFramework can't find a class / What does this Spring xml mean?

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea

I'm trying to run unit tests in IntelliJ IDE, and one of them fails with this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: #[cache.provider:com.foo.bar.caching.service.BasicMemcache]
```

So I search for that string and I find it in my services.xml file here:

```
<bean id="catalogCacheProvider" class="#[cache.provider:com.foo.bar.caching.service.BasicMemcache]">
    <property name="servers" value="${memcached.catalog.servers}"/>
</bean>
```

I didn't set this up, but I'm required to maintain it.  I can't find any explanation for that spring syntax `#[foo.bar:bazClass]` so I don't know what that means.  Also, I know that the class it references certainly exists.

Any information you can share might help me figure this out.

Comment: I have never seen a class specification like this: class="#[cache.provider:com.foo.bar.caching.service.BasicMemcache]", I would expect to see: class="cache.provider:com.foo.bar.caching.service.BasicMemcache", share with me how the other specification works.

Comment: Looks like it could be a part of the Spring Expression Language ([SpEL](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html)), but it is not familiar to me.

Comment: @BillFromHawaii - If I understood that syntax, I'd be a lot closer to solving my problem.  :)  It's used elsewhere in other Spring files, and evidently without problem, but I don't understand it, and couldn't find it documented.

Comment: As Mike Kobit pointed out it looks kinda like SpEL it also looks a little like your trying to retrieve a system variable (but, again, not quite). Go to http://www.baeldung.com/2012/02/06/properties-with-spring/ where Eugen has just posted an article on spring properties and post a question at the end (you can post as a guest). He knows stuff like this and he always answers.